# Match a line having particular text and ending with _P within square brackets

Tags: regex

I have several lines of texts, for example, two of them below:

```
a[15].s16.l = (xy[11].s16.l > (50/*QUE-const:VECTWord->CC_Init_P*/))

xyz = Exh[(16/*QUE-const:VECT_dir->_num_P*/) & 0x0FU ];*/))
```

I want to match the line which is having "QUE-const" and ends with "_P" within square brackets [].

I wrote following regex:

```
\[.*QUE-const.*_P.*
```

but it is matching both the lines, rather it should match only second line.

Please check and coorect where I'm going wrong.

Comment: There are a lot of possible approaches to match what you need, the main two are 1) match the left-hand side context ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/crMQWI/4)), 2) match only inside square brackets ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/crMQWI/5))

Comment: Your second demo seems to be working best! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see my idea has been already taken.

Answer (score 8):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
\[.*?QUE-const.*?_P.*?\]
```

[Here is Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/5Ck6ra/1/)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
\[.*?QUE-const.*?_P.*?\]
##Matching [ and till QUE-const then match till _P(with non-greedy quantifier) till first occurrence of ] here.
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you were close. Here's my take on it:

```
^.*\[.*QUE-const.*_P.*\].*$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O1kN0v/1)

Explanation:

```
^                      # start of line
.*                     # match anything 0 to unlimited times
\[                     # match bracket 1
  .*QUE-const.*        # match string containing QUE-const ... 
  _P.*                 # ends on _P and !!! anything after (in your example that should match you have */ after _P ) 
\]                     # match bracket 2
.*                     # match anything after 0 to unlimited times
$                      # end of line
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) starting with `[^][]*` to not pass the square bracket boundaries while matching the text.

```
\[[^][]*QUE-const[^][]*_P[^][]*]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uyGhMo/1)

Or if you want to match the whole line:

```
^.*?\[[^][]*QUE-const[^][]*_P[^][]*].*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` match any char as least as possible
- `\[[^][]*` Match the opening `[` and then 0+ times char except `[` and `]`
- `QUE-const` Match literally
- `[^][]*` Match 0+ times any char except `[` and `]`
- `_P` Match literally
- `[^][]*]` Match 0+ times any char except `[` and `]` and then match the closing `]`
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TwAYUr/1)